# How to convert png to nrrd?

Tags: python, image-processing, medical-imaging

How to **convert png to nrrd**? I need help, thank you!
I use the following code:

```
    img = cv2.imread(imgPath)
    imgT = img.transpose(1,0,2)
    img3d = imgT[..., np.newaxis]
    nrrd.write(imgPath.split(".png")[0] + ".nrrd", img3d)
```

But the conversion **speed is very slow**. It takes me almost 8 seconds to convert 1 picture.

Comment: how big is the picture?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your conversion is so slow, but you could use SimpleITK to do it.  It shouldn't take that long.  Here's what that code would look like:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

img = sitk.ReadImage(imgPath)
# not sure exactly what you're doing with the transpose and 3d bit of code
sitk.WriteImage(img, imgPath.split(".png")[0] + ".nrrd")
```